# Toast Messages in Android

Tags: android, andengine, toast

I'm developing a game via Andengine for Android platforms. I created a LevelEditorScene and I wanna use Toast messages on it like:

```
 Toast.makeText(activity, " Upload Started ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But it creates an error. Here is the logCat:
http://s9.postimg.org/jfqwsvx7j/Captu1re.png

What is the problem, can u solve it?

---

Here are my whole codes:

LevelEditorScene.java

```
@Override
public void createScene()
{

    //ekrana eleman eklemek için
    setOnSceneTouchListener(this);



     Rectangle save = new Rectangle(100, 400, 80, 50, vbom){
           @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

               if(pTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
               {
                   Toast.makeText(activity, " Upload Started ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





                 /*  getAllObjectsData();
                   createXmlFile(x, y, distanceordirection, type);
                   */

               }
               return true;
           }
        };
     save.setColor(1.0f,0.4f,0.5f);
     registerTouchArea(save);
     attachChild(save);
  }
```

SceneManager.java

```
 public void loadEditorScene(final Engine mEngine)
{
    setScene(loadingScene);
    ResourcesManager.getInstance().unloadMenuTextures();
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.1f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            ResourcesManager.getInstance().loadGameResources();
            editorScene = new LevelEditorScene();
            setScene(editorScene);
        }
    }));
}
```

GameActivity.java

```
     public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws IOException
{
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
            {
                mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                SceneManager.getInstance().createMenuScene();
            }
    }));
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```

Comment: You're trying to modify the UI in a thread. Move your code to the onPostExecute if you have one.

Comment: Are you calling it from UI thread ?

Comment: it doesn't look an issue regarding to toast.you running a thread inside main,make it right.

Comment: What is the problem with posting error as text instead of image?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare

Answer (score 0):

if you use Toast in static function it must not work

you can do this add this before oncreate function:

```
static Activity thisActivity = null;
```

and in oncreate function:

```
thisActivity = this;
```

and then you can use Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(thisActivity , "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```